# DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, set the cursor at the beginning of the cell content

Tags: c#, winforms

My datagrid has two textbox columns and two button column. I was trying that when user clicks on button then adjacent textbox cell will be in edit mode and cursor will be placed there.

My textbox columns are in readonly mode.

So I wrote code in cell enter that

```
private void dgView_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == 2)
        {
            DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell textBoxCell = dgv.CurrentCell as DataGridViewTextBoxCell;
            if (textBoxCell != null)
            {
                dgv.BeginEdit(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not getting error but my objective is not fulfill. Textbox cell is not getting in edit mode and cursor is not being placed on the textbox cell. So please tell me and rectify my code as result when I will click on button then adjacent textbox cell will come in edit mode and cursor will blink there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `CellClick` event. You don't really need to call `Focus()` just set the `CurrentCell` and `BeginEdit`:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        if (e.RowIndex == 2) {
            DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
            DataGridViewCell textBoxCell = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[col_index];
            if (textBoxCell != null) {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = textBoxCell;
                dgv.BeginEdit(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am getting error called "Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function." for the line dataGridView1.CurrentCell = textBoxCell;

Comment: You get that error if you use `CellEnter` event but try using `CellClick` as I said above

Answer (score 2):

First, set the focus to your grid and next, set the current cell.

```
dgv.Focus() = true;
dgv.CurrentCell = dgv[0,2];
```

Here is an example using your code from above:

```
private void dgView_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == 2)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell textBoxCell = dgv.CurrentCell as DataGridViewTextBoxCell;
        if (textBoxCell != null)
        {
            dgv.BeginEdit(true);
            dgv.Focus() = true;
            int col = e.ColumnIndex;
            dgv.CurrentCell = dgv[2,col]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Thomas: You got it.  I've edited my answer.  Let me know if I can help any further.

Comment: i am getting error called "Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function." for the line dgv.CurrentCell = dgv[2,col];

Comment: @Thomas: It's telling you that this would create a loop that is recursive on all paths, and it's right.  Is there another event you can hook to add the focus code?  Such as an OnClick or something else in your process?

Answer (score 0):

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{

```
var dataGridView = (sender as DataGridView);

if (e.ColumnIndex == "Your desire column index here")
{
            dataGridView.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
else
{
            dataGridView.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```